# Using Pattern-Matching Callbacks to download DataTables across multiple tabs in dash

Tags: python, plotly-dash

Suppose you have a dash dashboard with two tabs. On each tab is a download button and a DataTable. How can you write a single callback function which downloads the data table from that tab to a csv file?

Here is a minimum reproducible example:

```
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash import dcc, html, State, Output, Input, Dash, ALL, MATCH
from dash.dash_table import DataTable
import pandas as pd

app = Dash(__name__)

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['John', 'Jane', 'Bob'], 'age': [1, 2, 3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'colour': ['Red', 'Green', 'Blue'], 'favourite': [True, False, False]})

app.layout = dbc.Container(children=[
    dcc.Download(id="download_data"),
    dcc.Tabs([
        dcc.Tab(label='Tab 1', children=[
            html.Button("Download", id={"type": "download_data_table", "index": "tab_1"}),
            DataTable(
                data=df1.to_dict("records"),
                columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df1.columns],
                id={"type": "data_table", "index": "tab_1"},
            ),
        ]),
        dcc.Tab(label='Tab 2', children=[
            html.Button("Download", id={"type": "download_data_table", "index": "tab_2"}),
            DataTable(
                data=df2.to_dict("records"),
                columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df2.columns],
                id={"type": "data_table", "index": "tab_2"},
            ),
        ]),

    ]),
], fluid=True)


@app.callback(
    Output('download_data', 'data'),
    Input({'type': "download_data_table", "index": MATCH}, "n_clicks"),
    State({"type": "data_table", "index": MATCH}, 'data')
)
def download_table(n_clicks, data):
    if n_clicks > 0:
        return dcc.send_data_frame(data.to_csv, f"data.csv", index=False)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
```

I'm expecting that when I click the download button on the tab, it should pass the data from that tab to Download component which should download the data as a csv. However when I click the Download button nothing happens.

I think the issue is related to me incorrectly implementing the pattern-matching callback function.

I know I could write a separate callback for each download button, however I want to be able to generalise this solution to having many tabs and this would lead to lots of duplicated code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Here's an example using the [pattern matching callbacks](https://dash.plotly.com/pattern-matching-callbacks) feature in a Python Plotly Dash app:

> ***Note***: Dash 2.4+ required for use of `ctx.triggered_id`

In this case, you would actually want to use `ALL`, because you have just one `dcc.Download` component - against which *all* the different download buttons in the tabs *could* trigger. `ctx` is then used to determine which button out of all of them was the one that triggers any particular call of the callback function.

```py
import dash

from dash import ALL, Dash, Input, Output, State
from dash import ctx, dcc, html
from dash.dash_table import DataTable

import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import pandas as pd


app = Dash(__name__)

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"name": ["John", "Jane", "Bob"], "age": [1, 2, 3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {"colour": ["Red", "Green", "Blue"], "favourite": [True, False, False]}
)

app.layout = dbc.Container(
    children=[
        dcc.Download(id="download_data"),
        dcc.Tabs(
            [
                dcc.Tab(
                    label="Tab 1",
                    children=[
                        html.Button(
                            "Download",
                            id={
                                "type": "download_data_table",
                                "index": "tab_1",
                            },
                            n_clicks=None,
                        ),
                        DataTable(
                            data=df1.to_dict("records"),
                            columns=[
                                {"name": i, "id": i} for i in df1.columns
                            ],
                            id={"type": "data_table", "index": "tab_1"},
                        ),
                    ],
                ),
                dcc.Tab(
                    label="Tab 2",
                    children=[
                        html.Button(
                            "Download",
                            id={
                                "type": "download_data_table",
                                "index": "tab_2",
                            },
                            n_clicks=None,
                        ),
                        DataTable(
                            data=df2.to_dict("records"),
                            columns=[
                                {"name": i, "id": i} for i in df2.columns
                            ],
                            id={"type": "data_table", "index": "tab_2"},
                        ),
                    ],
                ),
            ]
        ),
    ],
    fluid=True,
)


@app.callback(
    Output("download_data", "data"),
    Input({"type": "download_data_table", "index": ALL}, "n_clicks"),
    State({"type": "data_table", "index": ALL}, "data"),
)
def download_table(n_clicks, data):
    if all(map(lambda x: x is None, n_clicks)):
        raise dash.exceptions.PreventUpdate
    # print(n_clicks)
    button_id = ctx.triggered_id.index
    # print(button_id)

    # Assuming all download buttons follow the naming format:
    # `tab_n` (1-based)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data[int(button_id[-1])-1])

    return dcc.send_data_frame(
        df.to_csv, f"data_{button_id}.csv", index=False
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, dev_tools_hot_reload=True)
```